# Install Python mysqlclient on Ubuntu docker container

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker

I want to install [Python's mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) package on a Docker container running [Ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/).  The installation fails because I don't have gcc installed in the container:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,7,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.7 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -fabi-version=2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer
    unable to execute 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

However, I do not want to install gcc in the container.  Is there a wheel available for mysqlclient?  I cannot find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a container and installed everything I needed to build mysqlclient.  I downloaded the .tgz and used `python setup.py bdist_wheel` to generate the Wheel file.  I copied over the wheel file to a directory mounted from my host machine, and installed it on the container where I wanted mysqlclient installed.  This way I didn't have to remove the packages I downloaded.  I saved the instance of the container with gcc as a separate image for future use.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the build dependencies, make the module, then remove them.

[Redis is a good example](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/8929846148513a1e35e4212003965758112f8b55/3.0/Dockerfile#L24) of how to build and cleanup in one step so you don't create a bulky image layer.

```
RUN buildDeps='gcc libc6-dev make' \
    && set -x \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/redis \
    && curl -sSL "$REDIS_DOWNLOAD_URL" -o redis.tar.gz \
    && echo "$REDIS_DOWNLOAD_SHA1 *redis.tar.gz" | sha1sum -c - \
    && tar -xzf redis.tar.gz -C /usr/src/redis --strip-components=1 \
    && rm redis.tar.gz \
    && make -C /usr/src/redis \
    && make -C /usr/src/redis install \
    && rm -r /usr/src/redis \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove $buildDeps
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing that.  I wanted to avoid doing that because apt-get shows that gcc has a lot of dependencies.  What I'll do instead build in another container that has everything and generate a wheel that I'll copy over to the container I'll actually use.  I assume it's possible to generate a wheel for Linux and reuse it (I ask because such wheels don't exist).

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for when you need to compile stuff but you don't want to pollute your image with the build stuff is to use [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/).

With multi-stage builds you build a first image with all tools and data needed for the compilation and you then build a second image where you copy only the result from the first image. It's also useful if you need some secrets (like SSH keys to access git private repos) but don't want those secrets in the final image.